# How to run same set of test for anonymous user and logged in user?

Tags: python, django, testing

I have a simple MovieDB app written in Django where webpages differ slightly between logged in view and guest user view.

I have a movies list page which doesn't change for logged in user and anonymous user except for sign-in/register links to sign-out. I am currently testing template used, no. of movies listed, movie title, nav-bar links (home, search page, login/register, sign-out, user account). I want to write tests to check these for both type of user **only once**.

My tests look like this:

```
class HomePageTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.response = self.client.get(reverse("core:home"))

    def test_home_page_is_accessible(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)

    def test_home_page_template(self):
        self.assertTemplateUsed(self.response, template_name="base.html")

    def test_site_name_renders_and_links_to_home_page(self):
        self.assertContains(self.response, "MovieDB", count=1)
        self.assertContains(self.response, f" href=\"{reverse('core:home')}\"")

    def test_sign_in_renders_and_links_to_sign_in_page(self):
        self.assertContains(self.response, "Sign In", count=1)
        self.assertContains(self.response, f" href=\"{reverse('account_login')}\"")

    def test_sign_up_renders_links_to_sign_up_page(self):
        self.assertContains(self.response, "Sign Up", count=1)
        self.assertContains(self.response, f" href=\"{reverse('account_signup')}\"")

    def test_home_page_for_logged_in_user(self):

        self.client.login(**self.credentials)
        response = self.client.post('/account/login/', self.credentials, follow=True)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn(reverse('core:home'),
                      response.redirect_chain[0],
                      msg="checks redirect after login")

        self.assertEqual(self.user.username, response.context['user'].username)

        self.assertContains(response, "Change E-mail", count=1)
        self.assertContains(response, "Sign Out", count=1)
        self.assertContains(response, f" href=\"{reverse('account_logout')}\"")

        self.assertNotContains(response, "Sign In")
        self.assertNotContains(response, "Sign Up")
```

I will have to re-write:

```
test_home_page_template
test_site_name_renders_and_links_to_home_page
```

and many others for logged in user which I am hoping to avoid.
I want to use the already written tests for logged in as well as anonymous user/guest.

Comment: Hi JenMan2020 it would be helpful if you could describe more of what you are seeking todo and what you have done so far.  An example of your problem is also helpful, check out this page for tips. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've added a code piece from my project to expand on my query.